# Error in trapezoidal rule decays faster than any polynomial?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth periodic function $C^{\infty}([0,2\pi])$. Let
$$ I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)dx.$$ 
The trapezoidal rule is given by 
$$ I_{N}=\frac{2\pi}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}f(x_{k}).$$
Then,

$$ I_{N}=I+2\pi\sum_{r \neq 0}\hat{f_{rN}},$$
where 
$$ \hat{f_{k}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{ikx}dx.$$
We know that for any integer $p >0$, and for any integer $k \neq 0$, that there exists a constant $C_{p}$ such that
$$ |\hat{f_{k}}|\le \frac{C_{p}}{|k|^{p}}.$$

Prove that the error in the Trapezoidal rule for a smooth period function decays faster than any polynomial as $N \to \infty$.

Any guidance on how to prove this?

Comment: Euler-Maclaurin summation formula does the job for you.

Comment: Trefethen and Weideman had a very nice SIAM Review article on the application of the trapezoidal rule to periodic functions, which is available on Trethefen's website [here](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/sirev56-3_385.pdf). (@Ian: This includes a discussion of the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula, with some critical remarks regarding its use as a proof of the desired result; see page 415.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you for the responses. I am confused though about what "faster than any polynomial as $N \to \infty$" means. Is it the trapezoidal rule applied to a polynomial, or the error in a polynomial interpolant, or something else?